# How to translate a Taylor Series into summation notation.

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, summation-method

If I was given an expanded form of a taylor series, how would I put it in summation notation? Do you just have to look for patterns and hope for the best? Are there any tips or tricks in order to find it?

TIA

Comment: Um, a Taylor series is usually in summation notation.  In fact, 'series' in general are usually in summation form.  Perhaps provide an example you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Sometimes it just doesn't seem to go.  $f(x) = \sum \frac {f^{(n)}(a) (x-a)^n}{n!}$  did you manage to find a pattern for $f^{(n)}(a)?$  If you did then that should give you an idea in how to put it into a nice form.  But, it is not uncommon to see.  $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + O(x^3)$ in which case we are sort of hand-waving away the higher degree terms as unimportant.